# JLabel constructor does not allow a null as a parameter

Tags: java

I want to set a null string to a JLabel:

`new javax.swing.JLabel(null);`

But the compiler does not allow this. Is there a way?

Comment: If the compiler does not allow it, you cannot do it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not use JLabel() or JLabel("");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(It would be helpful if you were to supply the compiler output).

`javax.swing.JLabel` has a single argument constructor to both a `String` and an `Icon`. If you supply `null` then Java does not know which constructor to use.

To disambiguate, you need to tell Java the *type* of `null` that you want.

The simplest way is to use a cast: `new javax.swing.JLabel((String)null);`

Comment: From compiler perspective, your answer is right. However, when question owner says "I want to set a null string to a JLabel"  it means he wants something he shouldn't want. From business perspective, when someone says "I want new Label(null)" correct answer is: You don't want